# Font-awesome in header in Ag-grid

Tags: angular, font-awesome, ag-grid

I would like add a icon in my header but fa-icon isn't working.

I have import in my app.component :

`import { faImages } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';`

and :

`faImages = faImages;`

In my columnDefs, I use :

`{ field : 'image', cellRendererFramework : ImageFormatterComponent,sortable: false, editable: false,headerComponentParams: { template: '<div class="ag-header-cell-label"><fa-icon [icon]="faImages"></fa-icon><span>Image</span></div>'}`

Comment: Have you tried to set class name so that you can define fa-icon. Once you give a fa-icon class name, then you can create custom class definition in Css file, pointing to the fa-icon name..

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example from the official documentation doing this:
[AG-Grid Header component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#example-header-component)

As you can see, the grid has icons next to the header title.

You can also check the code by check the plunkr link to test and try your own changes.